# Crystal Report "Error Detected by Export DLL" - Only Excel (Win7)

Tags: crystal-reports, report

When I use Crystal Reports export to Excel, the below error throw out:

> Error in file XXXXX. Error detected by Export DLL.

This error is only shown when exporting to Excel, others like Word/PDF are working perfectly.

I'm using win7.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this in two situations:

**Situation #1**

A long time ago, this was a known issue in Crystal Reports... 11 i think, not sure.

The solution was to install an update of ExporMoldeller.dll and crxf_pdf.dll.

It used to be available [in this link](https://www.securityfocus.com/bid/21261/solution)

**Situation #2**

If you are using .NET Datasets as the data source of the report, it can occur is something is wrong with the datasets. I've seen this happen when columns have no types defined explicitly, when there are multiple tables in the dataset and one of them is empty or the link definitions in Crystal Reports are worng, or when there is an empty cell in one table that was supposed to contain an image.